# Jetpack Compose Navigation: Get route of current destination as string

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using NavHost and a NavHostController to navigate in my Jetpack Compose application. To specify destinations, I use string-based routes:

```
NavHost(
    navController,
    startDestination = "FOO"
) {
    composable("FOO") {
        Foo()
    }
    composable("BAR") {
        Bar()
    }
}
```

I would like to retrieve the current route as a string (`FOO` or `BAR`) using the `navController`. The closest alternative I can find is `navController.currentDestination.id` that, however, returns a numeric ID, not the route as a string.

Is there any way to retrieve this value?

I'm using Jetpack Compose beta01 and Compose Navigation alpha08.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

From `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose` version `2.4.0-alpha01`, `androidx.navigation.compose.KEY_ROUTE` is replaced with `navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route`.

> The KEY_ROUTE argument has been replaced with the route property on NavDestination, allowing you to call navBackStackEntry.destination.route directly.
>
> [Release Note for 2.4.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha01)

Example code:

```kotlin
val currentRoute = navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
```

Or, if you need to observe the navigation:

```kotlin
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

when (val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route) {
    // do something with currentRoute
}
```

Comment: there is also `navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { }` listener for observing the current `destination` and `arguments`

Answer (score 3):

Resolved!

```kotlin
import androidx.navigation.compose.KEY_ROUTE

val currentRoute = navController.currentBackStackEntry?.arguments?.getString(KEY_ROUTE)
```

Not the cleanest solutions IMO, but it is used in the official Android documentation for navigating with compose: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation?hl=it

Answer (score 0):

For those who have a problem with getting a route from NavDestination object, such as me. Check the class type. There are two classes of NavDestination.kt and NavDestination.java. Cast it to NavDestination.kt to be able to get the route value.